# clases no reconocidas XMLRootElement

Tags: java, jaxb

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema me gustaria saber que opciones tengo para solucionar este tipo de errores que se presentan en rojo y admiracion en cada una de estas clases al lado izquierdo en el folder, resulta que importe un archivo de clases de Java a este proyecto que es un wsdl, las cuales me aparecen todas en admiracion color rojo , no se porque se presentan esos errores en rojo ,ese fue el achivo que me pasaron y lo importe al proyecto el cual permite probar los metodos con esas clases que se muestran,al principio pense que era un tema del  jdk yo estaba usando la ultima version , pero despues hace poco instale la version 8.0 y lo configure con netbeans y la variable de entorno con path para poder ver si dejaba de mostrar errrores , pero aun asi sigue mostrando este tipo de errores en rojo, por eso es el motivo de mi pregunta en este medio. Porfavor me gustaria saber respuestas claras y concisas muchas gracias por su atencion.

"las clases las importe dentro de la carpeta del proyecto en el explorador de archivos"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: En el "About" de Netbeans ¿Cuáles versiones tienes en Java y Runtime?

Comment: PD: como dice en la etiqueta de netbeans si le pasas el mouse encima....  Preguntas con esta etiqueta deberían referirse sólo al funcionamiento y configuración de NetBeans, no a dudas generales de programación (aunque se use NetBeans como IDE).